# Remove duplicate content in array from another array

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I have this

```
var a = ["1","2","3"]
var b = ["3","4","5"]
```

assuming "b" reads "a" and removes the 3 because it is repeated, how can I get this?

```
var c = ["4","5"]
```

Thank You!

Comment: [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 1):

Check if value exists on another array using `includes()`

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

You can remove values by using `filter()`

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

To do what you want:

```js
const a = ["1","2","3"]
const b = ["3","4","5"]
const c = b.filter((value) => !a.includes(value))
```

---

This has been answered before and is in detail: [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1187518/10975709)

Comment: If the question is a dupe, you shouldn't be answering it, just voting to close (thank you for doing that). Note that your answer is wrong anyway...

Comment: Thank You, but this returns ['3'], and not  ["4","5"]

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `set` and `spread operators`.
- `set` has property to have all unique value object.
- Below we are using `Set` constructor passing values using `spread` operator and it return an object so to get an array we are again passing that object with spread operator.

```js
let a = ["1", "2", "3"]
let b = ["3", "4", "5"]

let c = [...new Set([...a, ...b])];

console.log(c);
```

Comment: Is `Set` can keep the order of the data?

Comment: No, it does not guarantee the order.